# Possible application of Rouche's theorem to aproblem of complex roots of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, cv.complex-variables

The following holds:

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial in one variable $x$ of degree $3$ with complex coefficients
such that

a)
$$
P(-1)=P(1)=0
$$

Then

b)
the formal derivative $P^{'}(x)$ has a root in the region

$$
R = \lbrace z : \mid Re(z)\mid < 1 \rbrace
$$

of the complex plane.

Want to know if it is possible to prove this known fact by 
an appropriate application of Rouche's theorem.

Comment: What would a "no" answer to this question look like? The only thing I can think of would be to do some reverse math and find a reasonable theory where Rouch$\acute{e}$'s theorem is provable but this statement is not. However this statement can be proved easily by integrating the real part of $P′(x)$ and Rouch$\acute{e}$'s theorem is normally proved with some integration (correct?) so I suspect it would be hard to separate the two in this way.

Comment: How does it follow from Gauss-Lucas?  There is a third root of $P$ that may be outside the region $R$.  Actually, though, it follows from the fact that $P$ is of the form $P(x) = (a x + b )(x^2 - 1)$ that the product of the roots
of $P'$ is $-1/3$.  So at least one of those roots has absolute value $\le 1/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: [previous comment, making risibly wrong statement -- as pointed out by Robert Israel -- deleted]

Comment: dear amit: can you eventually ellaborate on your comment (line 3 of it mainly)
(e.g. transforming it with more work in an answer)
this will be useful in order to compare with robert's solution.